# Angular & Mongo query , return result closely equal to related to the search keyword

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, typescript

If text(firstname) == 'Eric' , it should return results . Any idea how we can tweek my code to return result as expected on the example ?

I am using angular on the front-end.

#Expected result (this would be top on the result)

```
Eric Gluthner
Eric Lecher
Erick Laspin
```

#and the other names with eric which would be less prio

```
Derick Ramp
Daniel Ericto
Raerick Fouler
```

#Code

```
getData(text: string): Observable<Identity[]> {
  const search_query = {
    query: {
      $or: [
        { firstName: { $like: text } },
        { email: { $like: text } },
      ],
      status: 1,
      $sort: {
        firstName: 1
      },
      // $limit: 5,  
    }
  };
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#perform-case-insensitive-regular-expression-match

Comment: @User863 can you post an example answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#perform-case-insensitive-regular-expression-match) pattern matching

```
getData(text: string): Observable<Identity[]> {
  const search_query = {
    query: {
      $or: [
        { firstName: { $regex: RegExp('^' + text) } },
        { email: { $like: text } },
      ],
      status: 1,
      $sort: {
        firstName: 1
      },
      // $limit: 5,  
    }
  };
```